# Что лучше использовать в индексе MongoId?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Здравствуйте,
Хочу понять, есть ли смысл заморачиваться с Mongo ObjectId.
Поле _id является уникальным и обязательным в коллекции MongoDb и может быть ObjectId представляющим из себя объект BSON, а может быть и просто строкой string.
Вопрос о быстродействии в целом при использовании эти двух способов, какой из них быстрее?

Comment: Какой из коней сферичнее...

Comment: значит вы считаете, что разницы в скорости обработки данных нет, это основано на опыте, тестах или еще чём то?

Comment: Я считаю, что для сферической "обработки" и разница в скорости будет столь же сферической.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ Sting или ObjectId - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896979/difference-between-storing-an-objectid-and-its-string-form-in-mongodb)

А для того чтоб понять как работают индексы советую создать колекцию размером в 50млн записей и поделать выборки с индексами и без.
А лучше изучите документацию - [ссылка на доку](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

Comment: большое спасибо, так и думал, но сомневался.